# Why am I getting exit code -1 without having any errors showing up in the IDE?

Tags: python

I'm currently getting into coding with Python and I wonder why, my program I wrote doesn't work as intended. Basically, I'm trying to make a password generator, but after the inputs, it just breaks.

```
import string
import random

nspecialchr = int(input("Number special characters: "))
nnum = int(input("Number of Numbers in password: "))
NChr = int(input("Number of letters: "))

LSpecialChr = ['!', '§', '$', '%', '&', '/', '#']
FLSecialChr = []
while nspecialchr > 0:
    FLSecialChr.append(LSpecialChr[random.randint(0, 6)])
    nspecialchr -= 1
FSpecialChr = ''.join(FLSecialChr)

LNnum = []
while nnum > 0:
    LNnum.append(random.randint(0, 9))
FNum = ''.join(LNnum)

LChr = []
while NChr > 0:
    LChr.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
    NChr -= 1
FChr = ''.join(LChr)

print(FSpecialChr + FNum + FChr)
pasue = input()
```

Comment: Can you include 1) how you are executing the program 2) what results you get from execution (stdout, error messages)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `nnum -= 1` at the end of the second loop (so you have a infinit loop). It is better to write

```
for i in range(nnum):
    LNnum.append(random.randint(0, 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors, in your second while loop you missed `nnum -= 1`  i have fixed them try this:

```
import string
import random

nspecialchr = int(input("Number special characters: "))
nnum = int(input("Number of Numbers in password: "))
NChr = int(input("Number of letters: "))

LSpecialChr = ['!', '§', '$', '%', '&', '/', '#']
FLSecialChr = []
while nspecialchr > 0:
    FLSecialChr.append(LSpecialChr[random.randint(0, 6)])
    nspecialchr -= 1
FSpecialChr = ''.join(FLSecialChr)

LNnum = ''
while nnum > 0:
    LNnum+=str(random.randint(0, 9))
    nnum -= 1
FNum = ''.join(LNnum)

LChr = []
while NChr > 0:
    LChr.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
    NChr -= 1
FChr = ''.join(LChr)
print(FSpecialChr + FNum + FChr)
pasue = input()
```

Output:

```
Number special characters: 5                                                                                          
Number of Numbers in password: 4                                                                                      
Number of letters: 3                                                                                                  
password generated is $#$%%1469Fsy
```